# Upper bound for 3-cycles in graphs of minimal degree 4.

Tags: graph-theory

If we have a graph G of minimal degree 4 with v vertices and e edges, what is a good upper bound on the number of 3-cycles in G?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Well, if G is a complete graph then the number of $3-$cycles is about $ve/3.$

Comment: @JoseCarlosSantos
The upper bound that I am hoping for is that if
$e \leq \binom{x}{2} + y + 2v$ where x is maximal, then
$c_3 \leq \binom{x+4}{3} + \binom{y+4}{2} + 6(v-x-1)$

Comment: I wanted to hear other ideas though since I may have been missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, the trivial upper bound for 3-cycles is $\binom{n}{3}$ ($n$ is number of nodes). You should set a constraint on the maximum degree of the graph to get a better result.

Comment: I meant if we restrain the number of edges, what is an upper bound of the number of three cycles. For example, with 6 vertices (or nodes as you call them) and 14 edges, the upper bound on the number of three cycles is 18 and not 20 as your bound implies. Can you come up with some kind of formula with v and e as variables for the upper bound on the number of 3 cycles?

Answer (score 0):

There is an exact formula for the number $c_3$ of 3-cycles
$$
c_3=\frac{1}{6}tr(A^3),
$$
where $A$ is the adjacency matrix of  graph.

Comment: This is a very nice formula, but can it be used to get an upper bound in terms of $e$ and $v$?